# How to add multiple markers on a google map parsed from json array?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I have written a program in which on button click i am getting the nearby atms from json . This is the link

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.052696,72.8713694&radius=1000&types=atm&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA8szrI9Ue4EwyUwTgz7Nk0c39qMal0pN4

I want to plot the atms on google map but the problem is only the last atm is being displayed on the map

Code : Method to get the atm names , latitude , longitude and vicinity

```
 public void showAtm(){
    String getAtmUrl =   
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json? 
    location="+lat+","+lng+"&radius=1000&types=atm&sensor=true
    &key=AIzaSyA8szrI9Ue4EwyUwTgz7Nk0c39qMal0pN4";
    try{
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(getAtmUrl).build();
        Call call = okHttpClient.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Map_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Request to atm 
                        locations failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws  
                IOException {
                Log.i("response ", "onResponse(): " + response);
                String result = response.body().string();
                Log.i("result",result);
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    String resultData = jsonObject.getString("results");
                    JSONArray urlDetails = new JSONArray(resultData);
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < urlDetails.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject json = urlDetails.getJSONObject(i);
                        geometry = json.getString(GOEMETRY);
                        vicinity = json.getString(VICINITY);
                        JSONObject jsonGeometry = new JSONObject(geometry);
                        String geoLocation = 
                        jsonGeometry.getString(LOCATION);
                        JSONObject jsonLatLng = new JSONObject(geoLocation);
                        atmLat = jsonLatLng.getDouble(LATITUDE);
                        atmLong = jsonLatLng.getDouble(LONGITUDE);
                        atmName = json.getString(ATM_NAME);
                        Log.i("JsonArrayAtm", "" + atmName);
                        Log.i("JsonArrayGeometry",geometry);
                        Log.i("LatLong",""+atmLat+" , "+atmLong);
                        Log.i("Vicinity", vicinity);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            moveAtmMap(atmLat ,atmLong );
                        }
                    });
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 ///////////////////////////// atm locations map ///////////////////
private void moveAtmMap(Double amtLatitude,Double atmLongitude){
    fragment.getMap().clear();
    CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
            .target(new LatLng(amtLatitude, atmLongitude))
            .zoom(16f)
            .bearing(0.0f)
            .tilt(0.0f)
            .build();
    String msg = amtLatitude+ ", " + atmLongitude;
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(amtLatitude, atmLongitude);
    fragment.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng));
    fragment.getMap().setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter()  
       {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.atm_custom_window, 
            null);
            TextView atmHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.atmName);
            TextView atmLocation = (TextView) 
            v.findViewById(R.id.atmLocation);
            atmHeader.setText(atmName);
            atmLocation.setText(vicinity);
            return v;
        }
    });
    fragment.getMap().setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    fragment.getMap().setTrafficEnabled(true);
    fragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    fragment.getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(position), null);
}
```

How do i achieve the above , can anyone suggest me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the method as,

```
private void moveAtmMap(Double amtLatitude,Double atmLongitude){
    fragment.getMap().clear();
    ...
}
```

so every time this method will be called, it will clear all previous markers and you will end up having only the last marker.

**Edit**

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < urlDetails.length(); i++){
    JSONObject json = urlDetails.getJSONObject(i);
    String geometry = json.getString(GOEMETRY);
    String vicinity = json.getString(VICINITY);
    JSONObject jsonGeometry = new JSONObject(geometry);
    String geoLocation = jsonGeometry.getString(LOCATION);
    JSONObject jsonLatLng = new JSONObject(geoLocation);
    double atmLat = jsonLatLng.getDouble(LATITUDE);
    double atmLong = jsonLatLng.getDouble(LONGITUDE);
    String atmName = json.getString(ATM_NAME);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            moveAtmMap(atmLat, atmLong, atmName, vicinity, geometry);
        }
    });
}
```

and change method like,

```
private void moveAtmMap(Double amtLatitude,Double atmLongitude, String name, String vicinity, String geometry)
```

If you want to clear markers from previous web service hit, then do it before you start adding markers for new service hit, like before the `for` loop.

Comment: i am getting multiple markers but the problem is when i click on all the markers i am getting the same information for all , which is the last json value , what to do for this ??

Comment: @narahari_arjun Reason for getting same info window for all markers is you have declared `atmName` and `vicinity` as Instance variables, so they will have values of last marker only. Instead of this try the way I edited in my answer.

Comment: yes yes instance variables , this is what exactly i was thinking of , thanks for pointing out .

Comment: I am having a small issue , inside my moveAtmMap method , when i click on any marker the name and vicinity shows the same json value which is the last one , any idea why is that so ? i have also used fragment.getMap().clear before the for loop but still no change .
I have also added a log statement before the setInfoWindowAdapter where i am getting all the json values correctly, but i am not getting all values of place and vicinity inside the getInfoContents method , can you suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line from the method moveAtmMap:

```
fragment.getMap().clear();
```

For the first time, write it before for loop in onResponse.

Comment: Why do you suggest me to do this before for loop ??

Comment: For the first time, you have to remove all the previously added markers and then add new ones based on the response of the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code,

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            MarkerOptions markerOptions;
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lattitude,
                           longitude)
            ).title("Title").snippet("This is snippet");

            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon));
            marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
```

Just replace lattitude,longitude with your values.
If you want to have instance of each marker,then you can put each "marker" object into hashmap with key as marker id. Let me know your feedback.

Note:  remove this line - fragment.getMap().clear(); because it will clear map everytime when compiler comes into loop and it will take only last object. this is what happenng right now.